# How to remove "Verifying "build-script-build" pop up

Tags: rust

I am running macOS and every so often I get the following pop up:

[image]

I believe this is the Rust Analyzer on VS Code but I am not 100% sure.

I cannot get rid of it, only minimize it.

Has anyone else run into this? Any way to make it disappear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use VSCode so can't relate to the specific problem you're having. That said, I recently disabled support for build-scripts in rust-analyzer (and proc-macros since those imply build-script support), I did this to increase the performance of RA (less compiling needed). The relevant rust-analyzer options are `rust-analyzer.cargo.buildScripts.enable` and `rust-analyzer.procMacro.enable`, but should be set to false.

Comment: Thanks - This worked! I also noted that I was using the official Rust extension and not the official rust-analyzer extension. The Rust extension has been deprecated in favor of the rust-analyzer extension and asked me to migrate to rust-analyzer.